# how to navigation bar at the bottom

Tags: android, android-layout, uinavigationbar

I have tied using this code..

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground" />
//parent views are Relative Layout then ScrollView
```

It is moving with the scrolling of the screen but I want navigation bar to be fixed, even after scrolling the screen, any can help me ??
Just like the Messenger app, I want it to be fixed!
[image: messenger]

Comment: "It is moving with the scrolling of the screen", what does this mean? is your view defined inside a Scrollview?

Comment: Your question would be greatly improved by 1. some screen video of what's happening (it's easy with android studio to grab video then convert to animated gif) 2. some more .xml code showing the parent(s) and siblings of BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"/>
```

I got it! It's fixed and not affecting with scrolling root layout is Relative Layout.
Thanks for your help Mr Amit Ghoswani

Answer (score 0):

-you can use following code or something like that....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: ```java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{phyla.admin.com.phyla/phyla.admin.com.phyla.plantDetails}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout"
```